# What is aperture of a lens?

Tags: optics, terminology, refraction, lenses

I read that *aperture of a lens* is the surface from which *refraction* takes place and it is represented by the *diameter* of the *lens*.

So, by saying that the aperture refers to the surface from which refraction occurs, do we mean that the surface area of the curvature would be the numerical value of the aperture.

And since the surface area of the curvature depends on the diameter, would that explain why it is represented by the diameter?

Comment: Where did you read this definition?

Comment: I only read that aperture is the surface from which refraction takes place and that it is represented by the diameter of the lens from **Lakhmir Singh - Physics for Class 10**. The rest is just a guess and I'm asking for confirmation

Comment: A flat or plane glass have infinite radius or no curvature. Still it can be cut down into cylindrical shape having circular face or surface of finite radius.

Answer (score 0):

The aperture of a lens is the working area of a lens: practically diameter of a beam which is refracted. If you place a pinhole with a variable diameter (sometimes called an aperture) before the lens, you can decrease the working area of the lens up to 0. Opening the pinhole fully, you obtain the full working area which is indeed represented by a diameter of the lens. In this way, a photographer could change the depth of the field (a parameter characterizing how many planes of a volumetric object are in focus).

P.S. Don't mix it up with a numerical aperture (NA) which has another sense, though related